# DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling `<<` to an ActiveModel::Errors message array in order to add an error is deprecated. in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6.1, ruby-2.7

Ruby - 2.7.3
Rails - 6.1.3.2

DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling `<<` to an ActiveModel::Errors message array in order to add an error is deprecated. Please call`ActiveModel::Errors#add` instead. (called from validate at /var/home/application_name/app/models/contacts.rb:4)

```
1.class AssociatedProgramValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
2.  def validate(record)
3.    unless record.user.programs.pluck(:name).include? record.program_name
4.      record.errors[:program_id] << "No #{record.program_name} found on user"
5.    end
6.  end
7.end
8.
9.class Contacts < ApplicationRecord
10.
11.  include ActiveModel::Validations
12.end
```

Please give some suggestion.

Comment: My suggestion is to start by reading the error message. It says: *"Please call `ActiveModel::Errors#add` instead"*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect it should be:

`record.errors.add(:program_id, message: "No #{record.program_name} found on user")`

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add

Answer (score 1):

In testing, it looks like the actual equivalent is

`record.errors.add(:program_id, "No #{record.program_name} found on user")`

I suspect the use of "message" instead of using it as an error type might be a better idea, but your code may not handle the difference without adjustment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31379662)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say.  It is nearly the same answer as the previously accepted answer, except that the previously accepted answer is slightly incorrect.  I can't comment on that other answer, so what do you suggest?  Just not answering to help clarify?

Answer (score -1):

Errors were changed from a hash to an object by work by lulalala for Rails 6.1. [And the following is taken from their comprehensive blog post on it.](https://code.lulalala.com/2020/0531-1013.html)

> **Avoid modifying the hashes directly**
>
> In the past you can add new errors by appending messages directly on
> to the hash:
>
> ```
> book.errors[:title] << 'is not interesting enough.'
> book.errors[:title].clear
> ```
>
> This would now also raise a deprecation warning, because it is no
> longer the source of truth, but generated from the Error objects when
> called. Instead always use the add interface, or enumeration methods:
>
> ```
> book.errors.add(:title, 'is not interesting enough.')
> book.errors.delete_all { |error| error.type == :too_long }
> ```
>
> Manipulating the following will have no effect:
>
> - errors itself as a hash (e.g. errors[:foo] = 'bar')
> - the hash returned by errors#messages (e.g. errors.messages[:foo] = 'bar')
> - the hash returned by errors#details (e.g. errors.details[:foo].clear)